# Disabling / Enabling a select based on the value

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is enable the breed drop down when the value changes from All pets, and when the user clicks back on All Pets the breed drop down becomes disabled again. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2yWeN/

```
   <form id="filter" class="filter" action="http://dev/petlist/public/site/index" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">  
       <select name="petsDropDown" id="form_petsDropDown">
         <option value="allPets">All Pets</option>
         <option value="barnyard">Barnyard</option>
         <option value="bird">Bird</option>
         <option value="cat">Cats</option>
         <option value="dog">Dogs</option>
         <option value="horse">Horse</option>
         <option value="pig">Pigs</option>
         <option value="smallfurry">Smallfurry</option>
      </select>          
      <select name="breedDropDown" id="form_breedDropDown">
         <option value="select_breed">Select Breed</option>
      </select>        
   </form>


   $(function(){
      if($("#form_petsDropDown option:first").attr('selected','selected')){
         $('#form_breedDropDown').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
      $('#form_petsDropDown').change(function() {
         $('#form_breedDropDown').prop('disabled', false);
         if ($('#form_petsDropDown allPets:selected').text() == 'All Pets'){
            console.log('worked');
            $('#form_breedDropDown').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         }

      });
   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#form_petsDropDown').change(function(){
    $('#form_breedDropDown').prop('disabled',($(this).val()=='allPets'));
}).change();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2yWeN/6/)**

Comment: That worked, as soon as stack will let me accept this answer I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set `#form_breedDropDown` to `disabled` initially via the HTML:

```
<select name="breedDropDown" id="form_breedDropDown" disabled>
    <option value="select_breed">Select Breed</option>
</select>
```

And then vanilla JS (I know you wanted jQuery, but since people have already provided those options, I figured what the hell ... its faster and educational):

```
document.getElementById('form_petsDropDown').addEventListener('change',function() {
    var self = this,
        breed = document.getElementById('form_breedDropDown');

    if(self.value === 'allPets'){
        breed.disabled = true;
    } else {
        breed.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Or simplified a bit:

```
document.getElementById('form_petsDropDown').addEventListener('change',function() {
    document.getElementById('form_breedDropDown').disabled = (this.value === 'allPets');
});
```

This only works with W3C-compliant browsers though, so not for older (IE8-) stuffs. If you want to ensure cross-browser compatibility, you can use the jQuery selector for ease:

```
$('#form_petsDropDown').on('change',function() {
    document.getElementById('form_breedDropDown').disabled = (this.value === 'allPets');
});
```

The function's contents will still work, so it'll still be a lot faster.